# numbering sections from custom sections (not the default title)

Tags: r, r-markdown, papaja

I would like to number sections in the document with papaja and noticed the solution in #85 and #332 (https://github.com/crsh/papaja/issues/). However, when I use "numbersections: true" or "\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}", the numbering starts from the "The title". I wonder if there is a way to number sections from a custom section, e.g., *Introduction* in Screenshots below, (not from the default "The title").

[Screenshots of the generated pdf file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTGmu.png)

Comment: This was a bug in the LaTeX template and should now be fixed. Try installing the most recent development snapshot: `remotes::install_github("crsh/papaja@devel")`.

Comment: Thanks. The title is not numbered now.